# RosJava issue 70 fix problem

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the fix located here:

http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/detail?id=70

The new Android.xml file doesn't have a name or as attribute, which causes me to generate this error when rosmake'ing android_gingerbread:

```
  BUILD FAILED
  /home/craig/ros_workspace/rosjava.android/android_gingerbread/build.xml:4: The following error occurred while executing this line:
  can't include build file file:/home/craig/ros_workspace/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/android.xml, no as attribute has been given and the project tag doesn't specify a name attribute
```

So trying to solve my own problem even though I have relatively no knowledge in this area I plugged in the name="android" and tried making it again. This caused me to receive:

```
  BUILD FAILED
  /home/craig/ros_workspace/rosjava.android/android_gingerbread/build.xml:4: The following error occurred while executing this line:
  /home/craig/ros_workspace/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/android.xml:64: taskdef class com.android.ant.NewSetupTask cannot be found
   using the classloader AntClassLoader[]
```

Sorry to be asking so many questions, I really am trying to get this working on my own. I'm just very inexperienced at this stuff and am having trouble figuring it all out.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11888/rosjava-issue-70-fix-problem/) by [mouser58907](https://answers.ros.org/users/1327/mouser58907/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2011-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Look at the android_tutorial_pubsub/build.xml for an example of how your build.xml should look. Also, make sure you've installed the last Android SDK and ADT.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2011-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mouser58907](https://answers.ros.org/users/1327/mouser58907/) on 2011-11-14**:
Updating and re-downloading files seems to have fixed this issue. I'm getting very close, thanks for your help, Damon.